# Login Page to verify NIC number

Tags: asp.net

I am facing the followingj problem: I have a database on Access 2010 with fields `NIC`,`Active` and `Page`, all are of number types. I want to create a login page that takes `NIC` (numeric) as an input from the user and then redirects them to specific page as per their NICs.

Different people will see different pages.. I am getting an error in `ExecuteScalar` command, maybe my query is not correct or maybe `ExecuteScalar` can't hold the query... I am getting `data type mismatch` error.

```
try
{
    FirsstPage f = new FirsstPage();
    SecondPage second = new SecondPage();
    oledcon.Open();

    string NIc = ( TextBox1.Text);
    // string query = "select * from LogINTable where NIC='" + NIc + "'AND Active=0 AND page=1";
    //string query = "select * from LogINTable where NIC='" + nic + "'AND Active=0";
    string query = "SELECT * FROM LogINTable WHERE NIC= '" + NIc + "' AND Active=0 AND page=1";
    //string query = "select
    OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand( query,oledcon);
    string a = (string) comm.ExecuteScalar();
    if (a != null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("FirsstPage.aspx");
        string update = "update into LogINTable Active='1' where NIC='" + NIc + "' ";
        //OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand();
        //int b = Convert.ToInt32( com.ExecuteScalar());
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("SecondPage.aspx");
        string update = "update into LogINTable Active='1' where NIC='" +NIc + "' ";
    }

    oledcon.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Label1.Text = ex.Message;
}
finally 
{
    oledcon.Close();
}
```

Comment: I more or less rewrote your entire question to be actually readable, remove all the *l33t sp34k* and such. Pay some attention to presentation if you want people to take the time to respond, if they have to spend 5 minutes first to understand the question they'll be less willing to help.

Comment: It's almost always a bad idea to `SELECT *` (except in `EXISTS()` clauses), and especially here where you're only wanting a single column's value

Comment: If that `NIC` column is numeric, why are you putting that value in quotes?

Comment: Please use parameters, to prevent [sql-injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are using ExecuteScalar with wrong query.

```
string a = (string) comm.ExecuteScalar();
```

ExecuteScalar() will return single value as a result from query.

Please change your query to the query like blow which return single value from database in place of entire colomn

```
Select NIC FROM LogINTable WHERE NIC= '" + NIc + "' AND Active=0 AND page=1"
```

Source :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i am still getting this error: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.